# Can a parameter be based on a calculated field in SSRs

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2012

I have a calculated field in my table, I want my parameter selection be based on the calculated field. can this be done ? Or is there an alternative way around this?

thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details? It is not very clear what you are asking

Comment: please provide your table structure and more details about your issue.

Comment: Is your calculated field in the table itself in SQL Server or is it in the dataset in SSRS?